# Git on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: git, repository, raspberry-pi3

Having trouble connecting a git init'ed directory with a repository on github.

Followed the instructions on github after creating the repo there.

Here is what I tried,

[image]

Strange that I am asked to config my username and email, when they are already configured with git.

This particular directory is where I've set up node and an Express app.

[image]

Tried $ sudo git checkout -b master

[image]

But the same output with  git commit.

Thanks,

Comment: Your initial commit failed... repeat it!

Comment: I repeated it and I get the same thing.

Comment: `git checkout -b master` ?

Comment: What's wrong with the question? Why the vote down?

Comment: That gives me,  error: Unable to open .git/HEAD.lock for writing
Switched to a new branch 'master'

Comment: Ah that works with sudo.

Comment: But git commit gives the same result as before, thanks for your help

Comment: I see... you did not have the right permissions. Are you sure you should be root? However: I think it now asks you again for the email, since you are a different user (root). Just go ahead as you did before (if you really want to do this as root).

Comment: Oh! That worked. I see now. Thanks a lot

Comment: do you actually want to be root? I dont think you do

Comment: Not particularly, but what's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

git config will record your settings in your global config (`/home/yourAccount/.gitconfig`)

But `sudo git ...` will look for configs in `/root/.gitconfig`

But in your case, it is best to init, add and push as your account instead of root.